# Comforter Vs. blanket

Tags: difference, usage

Is there a difference between [blanket](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/blanket) and [comforter](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/comforter)?

Today, by googling and looking for the name of the cover of the **blanket** I found that it is called "**comforter cover**" and then I saw that the meaning of comforter is the the same as blanket allegedly. Is it indeed the same and it is used the same as a synonym?

Comment: A comforter is usually synonymous with "duvet". It is a thick blanket filled with down or some other insulating material, whereas a blanket is thin and usually used when someone is sleeping on the couch and wants to keep warm.

Comment: Blankets are usually woven.  Comforters can be made of stitched pieces of fabric.

Answer (score 3):

At least in my (American English) usage:

**Blanket**: a warm bed covering that is much thicker than a bed sheet, but is only a single layer of material. It's usually woven or felted.

**Afghan**: a blanket that is coarsely crocheted. More associated with warming your lap while sitting than with a bed covering.

**Throw**: a light blanket meant to be draped (thrown) across a chair or sofa and used by the chair's occupant if necessary.

**Bedspread**: a colorful, medium-weight bed covering that makes the bed look attractive when fully made up.  It may or may not be removed for sleeping.

**Comforter**: a warm bed covering that has a decorative cover and some sort of filling (down, polyfill, foam, etc.), but is sewn shut.  You cannot remove the filling. Often used instead of a bedspread.

**Quilt**: structurally much like a comforter, but the cover is often made from many pieces of cloth sewn together in a decorative pattern, and then the whole thing is "quilted", which means criss-crossed with stitching. Popular as folk art.

**Duvet**: A more recent European import, once rare in America but now increasingly common (the comforter is becoming an endangered species as compared to the duvet). A very plain cloth envelope filled with thick fluffy filling like a comforter. Unlike a comforter, there is a separate **duvet cover** that is decoratively colored and can be removed and washed separately.

Comment: In British English there is also the Eiderdown, a type of quilt stuffed with eider duck down.

Answer (score 1):

In a sense, the two of them refer to about the same thing. However, they aren't usually interchanged. Usually, a blanket is smaller and thinner. It can be used in a lot of situations. However, a comforter is usually larger, thicker, and only used on a bed.

In addition, **"blanket"** is used more in informal speech. **"Comforter"** is used more in formal speech, especially when discussing items in business, or making a recommendation to a customer.

Comment: Also, there is a distributional difference. "Blanket" is found in both UK an US English. "Comforter" (in this sense) is restricted to American English.